# Assign a group to values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns(20) and rows (16404). One the columns is ['age']. I would like to be able to plot other metrics such as ['Income'] over a category of age. 
Ex: What's the income for all the Males under 20 years old or Females aged between 20 and 40.

I tried this type of condition:

```
for i in range(len(df['age'])):
    if df['age'][i]<25 and df['Gender'][i]==1:
        df['group'][i]=1
```

But I get the following error: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Could you please indicate me how to assign a group to a row depending on these conditions please?

All the series are int64

Best

Answer (score 2):

1. Ambiguous error can be solved by `(df['age'] < 25) & (df['Gender'] == 1)`  Note that I used an `&` instead of `and`.
2. if you did that, you are evaluating an entire column and assigning an entire column for every row which is very wasteful.

Do this to get booleans

```
df['group'] = df['age'].lt(25) & df['Gender'].eq(1)
```

you can convert that to integers `0` and `1` in many ways

```
df['group'] = df['group'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi, it indeed helps. What if I wanted to put several other conditions, and thus, more groups than 2. Would this method work?

Comment: You can put as many conditions as you'd like.  Just use `&` and `|` to evaluate element by element `and` and `or` operations on Pandas Series objects.  Notice that I used the `lt` method instead of `<`.  This acts to save me a parentheses.  Without it, you'd need to wrap your conditions in parentheses.

Comment: @trollster if that is the case, then the answer is, it depends on the specification.  Also, that comment was civil and useful.  Not what I'd expect from someone with your name (-:

Answer (score 1):

```
cond_1 = df['age'] < 25
cond_2 = df['Gender'] == 1
df['group'] = np.where(cond_1 & cond_2, 1, 0)
```

It will assign `1` where both conditions are satisfied and `0` everywhere else.

Taking into account your comments, this method doesn't have to be binary. You can include as many conditions as you need and you can substitute the `1` for any int or str you want. Moreover, you can change the `0` to `np.nan`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your help, this does work. What if I wanted to put several other conditions, and thus, more groups ?

Comment: You can keep adding conditions in the same way using `&` for `and` and `|` for `or`.

Comment: But it seems that this method is binary, when I either assign all of the values or none of them. I would like to assign only the ones respecting the condition.

Comment: That's not how this function works. The general format of `np.where()` is np.where(_condition_, _True_, _False_). It returns an `ndarray` that can become a pandas Series. You can use `np.nan` instead of zero if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use apply method instead (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)):

```
def your_function(row):
    if row['age']<25 and row['Gender']==1:
        return 1
    else: return 0

df['group'] = df.apply(your_function,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.